# How to bind table data dynamically to pdfmake table body using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, pdfmake

I have created a HTML Table and I want to download selected columns into pdf using pdfmake.

HTML markup:

```
<div id="tablediv">
<table id="stockalloctbl_1">
<thead>
<tr role="row">
<th>Col_A</th>
<th>Col_B</th>
 <th>Col_C</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>data1</td>
 <td>data2</td>
  <td>data3</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>gama1</td>
<td>gama2</td>
<td>gama3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>vega1</td>
<td>vega2</td>
 <td>vega3</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>theta1</td>
<td>theta2</td>
<td>theta3</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Export" onclick="Export()" />
</div>
```

CDN links are:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js" rel="stylesheet" ></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js" rel="stylesheet" ></script>


<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <link rel="Stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
```

jQuery logic:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        "use strict";         
          Export();
});

function Export() {
    //$("tr").each(function () {
    //    alert($(this).children("td:eq(0)").text());
    //    alert($(this).children("td:eq(1)").text());
    //    alert($(this).children("td:eq(2)").text());
    //});

    var a = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
    var b = ['Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3'];

    var docDefinition = {
        content: [
            {
                table: {
                    headerRows: 1,
                    widths: ['*', 'auto', 100],
                    //body: [
                    //    ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'The last one'],
                    //    ['Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4'],
                    //    [{ text: 'Bold value', bold: true, fillColor:"green"}, 'Val 2', 'Val 3', 'Val 4'],
                    //    ['V 1', 'V 2', 'V 3', 'V 4'],
                    //]

                    body: [a,b,] // here I want to pass dynamic data
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    // download the PDF
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('optionalName.pdf');
}
```

This is the jafiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/5cmaz0ug/1/

In the above `Export()` method code is working fine but I want to pass the data dynamically to this `body: [a,b,]` {how many rows are there to that table that all rows td should pass dynamically to this body}

I'm not sure how to pass dynamic data.

Please suggest me how to pass table rows td data dynamically to the body.

Hope you understand my issue and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Are you looking to have the first element in the array be the thead columns (Col_A etc..) then each TR in the tbody will be a separate element in the array?

Comment: Hi @imvain2 thnx for your comment and I want to download the html table as pdf format except `Col_C` data so I want to pass the `Col_A` and `Col_C`  td data as dynamically. Please suggest me.

Comment: Alternative approach: Why not use DataTables, which supports exporting the table (with dynamic data) to PDF. You can also specify which columns to include/exclude. There are various questions on Stack Overflow covering this subject, as well as the [official examples](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/), which include PDF examples.